# How to make ehcache reconnect with remote cache peers after network failure?

Tags: java, ehcache

I'm using ehcache 2.8.2, and I notice problems with one of my nodes failing to recover (  I have 5 or so in a test in environment ). Turning the logs down to debug level I can see that I get

```
DEBUG  (pool-4-thread-1) rmiUrl is stale. Either the remote peer is shutdown or the network connectivity has been interrupted. Will be removed from list of remote cache peers
```

A couple of times ( once per other node ) followed by log silence until the server is cycled.

I think maybe its incorrectly configured, but I can't find the relevant documentation on this section and its not obvious to me what I have to configure.

Does anyone know how network reslience is handled in the configuration ?

Edit :

Current configuration details ( simplified ) :

Ehcache :

```
<ehcache>

<diskStore path="/var/patelm5/cache"/>

<cacheManagerEventListenerFactory class="" properties=""/>

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                    multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                    multicastGroupPort=4446"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"/>

 <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
 />

</ehcache>
```

Spring.xml

```
<bean id="availabilityMonitorEhCache" class="org.patelm5.core.spring.ExtendedEhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehCacheManagerFactory" />
    <property name="cacheName" ref="AVAILABILTY_MONITOR_CACHE_NAME" />
    <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="1" />
    <property name="eternal" value="false" />
    <property name="overflowToDisk" value="false" />
    <property name="diskPersistent" value="false" />
    <property name="diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds" value="300" />
    <property name="timeToLive" value="36000" />
    <property name="timeToIdle" value="36000" />
    <property name="cacheEventListener" ref="defaultCacheEventListener" />
    <property name="bootstrapCacheLoader" ref="bootstrapCacheLoader" />
</bean>

<bean id="bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" />
<bean id="cacheEventListenerFactory" class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" />

<bean id="bootstrapCacheLoader" factory-bean="bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" factory-method="createBootstrapCacheLoader">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="bootstrapAsynchronously">true</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheEventListener" factory-bean="cacheEventListenerFactory" factory-method="createCacheEventListener">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="replicateAsynchronously">false</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Excellent question but if you ask a question about configuration, you should post the relevant bits of your configuration and mask out any bits that might be damaging to you (username, password, IP, etc.)